# Close react button dropdown menu on clicking or hovering outside of menu area

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

In my react application one of the component is creating a button dropdown menu like below.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a onClick=doSomething href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a onClick=doSomething href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a onClick=doSomething href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

How can I close this menu if someone clicks/hovers anywhere outside of this menu area?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't use jQuery events and DOM manipulations inside your React, you are missing the point.
**You have a `state` use it!**

In the following example you can see i removed all `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js` files and kept only the `bootstrap.css`.
I use the `state` in order to show / hide the `<ul>` list (i've set it to `display: block` in order to override the default `display: none` of `bootstrap.css`).
I have set 2 main handlers regarding showing and hiding the `<ul>` and 1 handler for the `onclick` of each item:

1. `toggleShow()` - Toggle the `show` property in the `state` attached to the `onBlur` of the button.
2. `hide()` - Hides the `<ul>` via the state of course (it does one
   more thing which i will explain).
3. `doSomething()` - Will fire on click of an item.

This scenario has a nice challenge though, when we hide the `<ul>` we can't handle the click event.

**But why?**

Because we don't really hide it, it doesn't get rendered when `state.show` is false. So basically there's kind of a race condition of the `setState` the triggers a re-render against the handler of the `doSomething` event handler which can't run.
So the challenge here is to determine if active element that triggered the `onBlur` event of the button is the item inside the `<ul>`. If it is, then we need to let the item trigger it's `onClick` event and only then set the state and "hide" the .
We did that with the help of `relatedTarget` that attached to the `event`. This is the active element that we are looking for, and if we have one and it's not `null` then we trigger it's click event (no matter what element it is by the way as we don't care), and only then we set the state with `show: false`.

**A working example:**

```js
class DropDown extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      show: false
    }
    this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);
    this.toggleShow = this.toggleShow.bind(this);
    this.hide = this.hide.bind(this);
  }

  doSomething(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
  }

  toggleShow(){
    this.setState({show: !this.state.show});
  }

  hide(e){
    if(e && e.relatedTarget){
      e.relatedTarget.click();
    }
    this.setState({show: false});
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="dropdown">
        <button 
          className="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
          type="button"
          onClick={this.toggleShow}
          onBlur={this.hide}
        >

        {"Dropdown Example"}
          
        <span className="caret"></span>
        </button>
        {
          this.state.show &&
        (
          <ul className="dropdown-menu" style={{display: 'block'}}>
          <li><a onClick={this.doSomething} href="#">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a onClick={this.doSomething} href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a onClick={this.doSomething} href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
        )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<DropDown />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Add `onMouseLeave={this.hide}` to the `ul` to get the hover out effect that the OP is asking for.

Comment: @totbar i would need to modify the logic a bit, if you hide it on mouse-out you can't click it.  beside the OP wasn't clear on how and where exactly the mouse out should  be attached to. but it's doable of course.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this. The easiest way you can achieve this is by either having event listeners to listen to the click events or write an onBlur function for the dropdown component.

```
  componentWillMount() {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
  }
```

And then you'll have to wrap your component inside the listener component.

Here is the working JS fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/vamshikrishna144/zukcpfr2/

Comment: it would have been better if you could have used bootstrap to get the same button and menu and could have demonstrated close menu operation on clicking outside

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal but that is not a part of the question :) What exactly is your concern?

Answer (score 0):

> onBlur = {() => console.log("Clicked outside")}

The above method is triggered when clicked outside the Dropdown. You can change the states etc to show or hide your div or react dropdown