# How to toggle menu icon to cross icon while click the menu icon in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I tried to create a website using ReactJS and i tried to **toggle the menu icon while click the menu icon** using onClick event using ReactJs. but it's not working. there is no error. but icon is not toggle. what's the correction?

```
import React, { component } from 'react';
import './Sidebar1.css'

class Sidebar1 extends React.Component {
        toggleicon() { <
            i class = "fas fa-times" > < /i >
        }

        render() {

            return ( < div className = "sidebar1" > < div className = "menueiconstyle" > < a href = "#"
                onClick = { this.toggleicon } > <
                i class = "fas fa-bars" > < /i > < /a > < /div >  < /div > );
            }
        }
        export default Sidebar1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Close react button dropdown menu on clicking or hovering outside of menu area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46203851/close-react-button-dropdown-menu-on-clicking-or-hovering-outside-of-menu-area)

Comment: You need to look into a VERY important part in react called `state`. You need a state variable (or hook) that will act as a boolean. If the button has been clicked, you update the state. I would highly recommend you look up react tutorials (even if it's just on Youtube), since this is one of the most core aspects of React, and one of the very first things you should learn. If you had done ANY (and I mean ANY) research before posting your question, you'd have realized that on your own as well. Take your time to go through the basics of whatever you're trying to learn before jumping in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a variable(boolean) for the corresponding toggle state
   ex: `[isClicked, setIsClicked] = React.useState(false)`
2. When the button is clicked replace the  class
   ex: `` <i class=`fas ${isClicked ? "fa-times" : "fa-bars"} ``
3. `setIsClicked()` should be used in button `onClick` event